# Spark worker keep removing and adding executors

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to build a spark cluster using a local Ubuntu virtual machine as the master, and a remote Ubuntu virtual machine as worker.
As the local virtual machine is running in a virtualbox, to make it accessible by remote guest, I forwarded the virtual machine's 7077 port to the host's 7077 port.
I start master by:

```
./sbin/start-master.sh -h 0.0.0.0 -p 7077
```

I made it listening on `0.0.0.0`, because if I use the default `127.0.1.1`, the remote guest won't be able to connect to it.
I start the worker by executing the following command on the remote machine:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker   
spark://129.22.151.82:7077
```

The worker is able to connect to the master, which can be seen on the UI:
[image: Screen shot]

Then I tried to run the "pi" example python code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf=SparkConf().setAppName("Pi").setMaster("spark://0.0.0.0:7077)
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

....
Once I run it, the program never stops, I noticed the program is always removing and adding executors, because executors always exits with error code 1. And this is the executor's `stderr`:

```
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-  defaults.properties
    16/02/25 13:22:22 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: 
Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
    16/02/25 13:22:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load 
native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java 
classes where applicable
    16/02/25 13:22:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: kxz138,adminuser
    16/02/25 13:22:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: kxz138,adminuser
    16/02/25 13:22:23 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: 
authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view 
permissions: Set(kxz138, adminuser); users with modify permissions: 
Set(kxz138, adminuser)
    **16/02/25 13:22:23 ERROR UserGroupInformation: 
PriviledgedActionException as:adminuser (auth:SIMPLE) 
cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:34935
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.15:34935**
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
```

I noticed the error here is actually a network problem. The worker is actually trying to access `10.0.2.15` which is the local NAT ip address of my virtual machine, but failed. 
  This error never occurs when I only deploy worker from my local computer. 
  Anyone has any idea why this error occurs? Why the worker is trying to access the ip address `10.0.2.15` instead of my public IP?

BTW, I've already set up the key-less ssh access from master to slave.

Comment: did u solve the issue , as Im facing the same as above :(

Comment: @RahulKoshaley Sadly no...I started to question my way of submitting script to clusters. I may have to use spark-submit to submit script instead of running the script directly from my IDE.

Comment: I do not understand , how spark-submit will solve the issue. By the way I solved mine. But it was a diff issue altogether

Comment: @RahulKoshaley How do you solve it?

Comment: Hi , My issue was different as I was making two spark contexts, but when I ran the job with single spark context, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by making sure that the VMs within the cluster belong to the same subnetwork. As an example, initially, I had set the IP `192.168.56.101` as the master node and `192.168.57.101` as the worker node with `255.255.255.0` as the subnet mask. But this means that both IP addresses are not within the same subnetwork. After I change the subnet mask to e.g., `255.255.0.0`, I could run my app properly. You may need to edit some configuration files accordingly as well (e.g., `~/.bashrc`,`conf/spark-env.sh`, `conf/slaves.sh`, `conf/spark-default.conf` and `/etc/hosts`)